# Both threads blocking on call to boost::mutex::lock()

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have a boost::mutex that's being used in two threads. The first thread is constantly locking and unlocking the mutex. The second thread only uses the mutex on a certain condition. When this condition occurs, both threads block on the lock. What could possibly causing this?

Some random facts about my program: The mutex is a data member of class shared between the two threads. In the second thread, I am passing a pointer to the mutex to the function that uses it, but in the first thread I'm using the mutex by reference.

Comment: can you post the code indicating how the threads use the mutex?

Comment: Just one idea. Do you have any recursive calls or circular dependencies between those functions? If yes, you'll have to use recursive mutex (if this is what you intended) or review just review your code, because it's going to create classic deadlocks.

Comment: I figured out that in the critical section of the first thread a Win32 function was being called that should only be called from the second thread since that thread created the Win32 window. I'm not sure what the SO etiquette says I should do in this case. The answer has little to do with the question I asked. Do we vote to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to unlock the mutex in the main thread after you signal the condition? Alternately, did you get into a deadlock situation?

Comment: Yes, a deadlock was occurring but not because of the mutex I was using, but because a different function was causing both threads to block on what I think is a Win32 event queue.